# Data insertion on join using sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table t1 and t2. I need to the aggregated value of "COUNT" and the time in a third table from each of these tables.

`t1`:

```
COUNT               TIME_AH
2                   17-MAY-16 12:00:00
3                   17-MAY-16 12:00:00
2                   17-MAY-16 12:00:00
12                  17-MAY-16 12:00:00
2                   17-MAY-16 12:00:00
12                  17-MAY-16 12:00:00
```

`t2`:

```
COUNT       TIME_ZH
1           17-MAY-16 12:00:00
22          17-MAY-16 12:00:00
3           17-MAY-16 12:00:00
4           17-MAY-16 12:00:00
```

`t3`:

```
OUTPUT_TABLE

COUNT_AH    COUNT_ZH    TIME_AH
19          30          17-MAY-16 12:00:00
```

I have tried the below code, but its giving incorrect output.

```
select sum(t1.count), sum(t2.count), sysdate
from t1,
     t2
where TIME_AH = (trunc(sysdate,'hh'));
```

Please help.

Comment: If you adjust some timestamps to other values, the sample data will make much ore sense describing the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `UNION` instead of a `JOIN` and a `CASE EXPRESSION`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN f.timetype = 'AH' THEN f.count else 0 END) as count_ah,
       SUM(CASE WHEN f.timetype = 'ZH' THEN f.count else 0 END) as count_zh,
       sysdate
FROM(
    SELECT t.count,t.time_ah,'AH' as TimeType FROM t1 t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT s.count,s.time_zh,'ZH' FROM t2 s) f
WHERE f.TIME_AH =  trunc(sysdate,'hh');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
select sum(t.a),sum(t.b),t.sysdate from (
select sum(t1.count) as a, 0 as b, sysdate
from t1
where TIME_AH = (trunc(sysdate,'hh'))
union all
select 0 as a, sum(t2.count) as b, sysdate
from t2
where TIME_AH = (trunc(sysdate,'hh'))) as t group t.sysdate
```